# For the normed spaces $X$ and $Y$, if $X$ is finite dimensional and $A: X \to Y$ is linear, how to find $x \in X$ s.t. $\|Ax\|=\|A\| \|x\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

As $X$ is finite dimensional $A$ is bounded, but I don't know how construct this element (with $x\neq0$). I could have a basis $\{e_n\}$ of $X$ and

$$\|Ax\| = \left\|A\left(\sum a_ne_n\right)\right\|=\left\|\sum a_n Ae_n\right\| , a_n \in \mathbb{F} (\mathbb{R} \text{ or } \mathbb{C)}, x\in X$$

take a basis $\{b_n\}$ of $Y$ (maybe infinite dimensional), so

$$\|Ax\|=\left\|\sum a_n\left(\sum_k c_k {b_n}_k \right)\right\| ,c_k  \in \mathbb{F}$$

But I don't know how to follow.

Comment: When you write ||A|| ||x|| in MathJax code, you see $||A|| ||x||,$ but when you write \|A\|\|x\|, you see $\|A\|\|x\|.$ I fixed that and a bunch of other things in your MathJax code. Including the fact that in $\{a_n\}$ the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ belong inside the MathJax code, not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The map $B(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\|A(x)\|$ is continuous where $B(01)$ is the closed ball of $X$ of radius $1$, since $B(0,1)$ is compact, there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=sup_{x\in B(0,1)}f(x)=\|A\|$.

Comment: This gives existence, but it doesn't construct the element